# Magnitude of length of line using vectors

Tags: vectors

> In triangle $ABC$, $\angle A = 30^\circ$, $H$ is the orthocentre and $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$. Segment $HD$ is produced such that $HD = DT$. The length $AT$ equals:
>
> a) $2 BC$
>
> b) $3BC$
>
> c) $\dfrac{4}{3}BC$
>
> d) none of these

Attempt:

Let $H$ be the origin. Then define $\vec a$, $\vec b$ , $\vec c$ directed towards vertices A, B and C respectively.

Given: $\vec d = \dfrac{\vec b + \vec c}{2}$

Therefore $\vec T$ directed towards point T from H = $\vec b+ \vec c$

$\implies \vec{AT} = \vec T - \vec A = \vec b + \vec c - \vec a$

Now I am facing trouble in finding the magntiude of $\vec b + \vec c - \vec a$.

How do I continue from here?

Comment: If $\triangle ABC$ is right angled, then $AT = 2BC$.

Comment: @peterwhy How??

Comment: Here $B$ and $C$ are interchangeable. If $\triangle ABC$ is right angled and $\angle ABC = 90^\circ$, then the orthocentre $H$ is at the right angle $B$. $D$ being the mid-point of $BC$ means $HD$ (i.e. $BD$) is extended to $T = C$. Then

$$AT = AC = \frac{BC}{\sin 30^\circ} = 2BC$$